# Ellipsize not working properly for a multiline TextView with an arbitrary maximum height

Tags: android, textview, multiline, ellipsis

I have a `TextView` with an unknown maximum height, which is dependent on the device's DPI/screen resolution. So, for instance, on and MDPI device this maximum height makes it possible to show only 2 lines at a time, a value that can be increased up to an undefined number.

My issue is related with the ellipsize functionality. Let's suppose that a certain device allows for 4 lines to be displayed. If I manually set the maximum number of lines, like this...

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/some_id"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:ellipsize="end" 
    android:maxLines="4"
    android:singleLine="false"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="This is some really really really really really long text"
    android:textSize="15sp" />
```

...everything works OK. If the text doesn't fit properly, then the ellipsis are added at the end of the fourth line, like this:

```
This is some
really really
really really
really long...
```

But I'd rather *not* set the number of lines as a static variable, as I would prefer to include support for any combination of DPI/screen resolution. So if I remove `maxLines` the ellipsis is no longer correctly shown at line four, showing instead an incomplete portion of text:

```
This is some
really really
really really
really long
```

If I slightly increase the `TextView` size, I can see that the rest of the text is still being drawn "behind" the other `Views`. Setting the variable `maxHeight` doesn't seem to work either.

I really can't seem to find a solution for this issue. Any ideas? If it helps, I'm working only with Android v4.0.3 and up (API level 15).

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Calculate how many lines fit into the `TextView` with `TextView#getHeight()` and `TextView#getLineHeight()`. Then call `TextView#setMaxLines()`.

```
ViewTreeObserver observer = textView.getViewTreeObserver();
observer.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        int maxLines = (int) textView.getHeight()
                / textView.getLineHeight();
        textView.setMaxLines(maxLines);
        textView.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(
                this);
    }
});
```

Comment: Note: the line height may vary! And therefor the method getLineHeight wont always work as expected. This could happen for example when using spannables to make the font size bigger in a specific part of the text.

Comment: Just adding a [link to the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getLineHeight()) for what Rolf added.

Comment: This answer works well up to API 27.  Since API 28 and 29, there is (by default) more spacing between lines.  For example, while `textView.getLineHeight()` returns `55` (I use Pixel 2 AVD), the actual height is `66` (or 67), including the extra space.  So far, the only way I can get this number (66) is via `textView.getLineBounds()`.

Comment: This is old, but gold

Answer (score 6):

The accepted answer works well up to **API 27**.  However, since **API 28**, if the line height was not set (by one of the follow methods), by default Android adds extra spacing between lines, but not after the last line.

1. Set attribute `android:lineHeight=...` ([documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:lineHeight)) in your layout XML
2. Calls `textView.setLineHeight(...)` in your source code.

To find out the new line height for API 28 and above, I used `textView.getLineBounds()`.

**Kotlin**

```
val observer = textView?.viewTreeObserver
observer?.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(object : ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {
    override fun onGlobalLayout() {
        textView?.let { view ->
            val lineHeight: Int
            lineHeight = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
                val bounds = Rect()
                textView.getLineBounds(0, bounds)
                bounds.bottom - bounds.top
            } else {
                textView.lineHeight
            }
            val maxLines = textView.height / lineHeight
            textView.maxLines = maxLines
            textView.viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this)
        }
    }
})
```

**Android Java**

```
ViewTreeObserver observer = textView.getViewTreeObserver();
observer.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        int lineHeight = textView.getLineHeight();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
            Rect bounds = new Rect();
            textView.getLineBounds(0, bounds);
            lineHeight = bounds.bottom - bounds.top;
        }
        int maxLines = (int) textView.getHeight() / lineHeight;
        textView.setMaxLines(maxLines);
        textView.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(
            this);
    }
});
```