# TextView does not ellipsize and is cutoff horizontally in the middle of a line

Tags: android, textview

I've been working on this issue for a few hours now and am at a loss.

I have an item in a recyclerview (orientation horizontal) that with which I have a paragraph of text. I'm expecting the text to ellipsize at the end of where it would fit into the TextView, but instead it gets cut off in a weird place: [image]

I've tried setting the description view to a fixed height, used `wrap_content`, changed to use `maxLines`, `lines` and all of them produce the same effect and do not ellipsize the  text. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong with this?

The code for this row is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="point"
            type="uk.geekhole.visum.database.models.BasePoint" />
    </data>

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="260dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="18dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="9dp"
        android:elevation="0dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="15dp">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:imageUrl="@{point.imageUrls[0]}"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/title"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                tools:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
                tools:src="@drawable/app_logo" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/background"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="105dp"
                android:background="@drawable/background_near_me_row"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:text="@{point.name}"
                android:textColor="@color/text_colour_near_me_title"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_normal"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/background"
                tools:text="Wollaton Hall" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/description"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:text="@{point.description}"
                android:textColor="@color/text_colour_near_me_description"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_smaller"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/title"
                tools:text="In the heart of nottingham this stunning park will leave you speechless, with breathtaking views from outside the hall, to the intriguing curiosities inside. Fun for all ages!" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</layout>
```

Comment: What happens if you change `description`'s width to `0dp` and add constraints to the start end to attach to the `parent`?

Comment: Which device is doing this problem?

Comment: @BenP. I have also tried that and unfortunately it didn’t work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ellipsize not working properly for a multiline TextView with an arbitrary maximum height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14173776/ellipsize-not-working-properly-for-a-multiline-textview-with-an-arbitrary-maximu)

Comment: @RyanMentley that does indeed appear to be / fix the issue. A shame that it's such a hacky fix though. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As posted by Ryan Mentley on the OP this appears to be and fix the issue: [Ellipsize not working properly for a multiline TextView with an arbitrary maximum height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14173776/ellipsize-not-working-properly-for-a-multiline-textview-with-an-arbitrary-maximu)

Not a very nice fix but it does the job.

Answer (score -1):

Use this

```
android:ellipsize="marquee"
```